# How to create a table that shows cumulative growth across all dates in particular date range using sql?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'd like to create a table using SQL that shows cumulative growth across a date AND also shows the value across each date in a particular date range (in this case from January 1st, 2016 to January 15th, 2016). Im having issues showing all dates in a particular date range.

```
data = [{'date':'2016-01-02','value':'1'},{'date':'2016-01-03','value':'3'},{'date':'2016-01-04','value':'3'},{'date':'2016-01-07','value':'2'}]
```

The following query is producing the below table:

```
select 
date, 
sum(value) over (order by date rows unbounded preceding) as value
from data
group by 
date, 
value
```

Below is initial table

```
date        value       
2016-01-02  1   
2016-01-03  4
2016-01-04  7    
2016-01-07  9
```

However, I'd like to produce the following table

```
date        value
2016-01-01  0           
2016-01-02  1   
2016-01-03  4
2016-01-04  7    
2016-01-05  7    
2016-01-06  7    
2016-01-07  9    
2016-01-08  9    
2016-01-09  9    
2016-01-10  9    
2016-01-11  9    
2016-01-12  9    
2016-01-13  9    
2016-01-14  9    
2016-01-15  9
```

Comment: mysql or redshift?

Comment: @vkp redshift! I should have been more clear

Comment: so you have a `date` table with all the calendar dates available?can you confirm that?

Comment: @vkp I do not have a date table with all calendar dates - How would I go about getting that, because I think that may help solve this

Comment: the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_datetable.html) says you have it?

Comment: @vkp - oh, I didn't realize! However, I dont understand how to query this 'date' table from redshift

Comment: never mind.. the table in the link was from the sample database redshift provides.